# Refer the cell containing the user defined function in that function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a user defined function which manipulates the cells in the same row and column. Can the function detect in which cell the function is inserted? I can as well pass Google Sheets formulas `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` as arguments to the user defined function. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your function writes some values into a cell. In that case, that cell would be known as the *active cell*. You can use the [`Selection`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection) class to get that cell as a `Range` object. Then, you can use the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) class methods as usual to work with that cell.

I will assume that your function writes the value using the [`Range.setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) method. If that is correct, then you can get the cell even easier because that method returns the `Range` object for [chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining). If these approaches don't work in your scenario, please share your code so I can help you better.